# Truffle for Windows: I can't make it work

Tags: truffle, windows

I've installed Truffle v3.2.1 for Windows. If I try to run:

```
truffle console
```

> Could not find suitable configuration file.

If I run:

```
truffle create:contract MyContract
```

I get nothing but command list.

Any ideas?

Comment: open cmd in the folder you have your Dapp and try to add .cmd like this: <B>truffle.cmd console</B>

Comment: no luck with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed with this command:

```
npm install --force -g truffle
```

It downloads and install all used modules.

Answer (score 3):

open a cmd and run testrpc, then open another cmd in the folder you have your Dapp and try to add .cmd like this:

truffle.cmd console

(not enough rep to comment, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Even, I had the same error.

> From the Doc

When using the Command Prompt on Windows, the default configuration file name can cause a conflict with the truffle executable.If this is the case, we recommend using **Windows PowerShell** or **Git BASH** as these shells do not have this conflict. Alternatively, you can rename the configuration file to *truffle-config.js* to avoid this conflict.

> NOTE

I tried changing the config file first, but then I got the same error of config file missing. But when I use it **Windows PowerShell**, it works like a charm.

Hope this helps

Comment: Running truffle console from powershell works for me

Answer (score 0):

Before running `truffle compile` make sure you are in proper folder. in linux with `pwd` command you can get your current directory. (in windows I don't know how can you get current directory)